# Finder.app preview pane and QuickLook stretch some of my photos

Tags: images, finder, quicklook, stretch

The Finder column view preview pane and QuickLook stretch many of my photos. But when I open the same photos in Preview.app, they look normal.

Screenshot:

[image: quicklook screenshot]

For example, download this image ([reaver.jpg](http://www.yellosoft.us/public/images/reaver.jpg)), and view it with Finder's column view. Now view it with QuickLook. It renders correctly in every other application, so there's something going wrong in how QuickLook/Finder get the image dimensions.

[image: original image]

This problem started happening in either Mac OS X 10.8.1 or 10.8.2.

Specs:

- Finder 10.8
- QuickLook v4.0 (555.0)
- Mac OS X 10.8.2
- MacBook Pro 2009

Also posted in [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19794171).

Answer (score 1):

The meta-data on your image appears to be incorrect. It says that its DPI is 72 in the horizontal direction, and 350 in the vertical direction.

It looks like QuickLook is trying to honor that and act as if you really had a camera with really strange long rectangular pixels instead of square pixels.

Given that its dimensions in pixels is 816 wide x 1023 high, that means your image thinks it's 11.3 inches wide by 3 inches high.

Fix your metadata and it should display correctly everywhere.

I'm guessing that the apps that display it correctly either don't pay attention to DPI, or they're calling BS on your ultra-rectangular pixels that your images claim to have.

Comment: Aye. And it's only QL/Finder that does this. So how can I get them to ignore that metadata?

Comment: @mcandre Just use a metadata editor (such as an image editor that lets you edit metadata) to fix the metadata.

Comment: I downloaded a bunch of random images from Flickr and some forums. I'd rather not try to recursively go through my hard drive to fix the metadata. It would be better if QL/Finder just handled this like every other image program.